# Highlighting Route on Xamarin Forms Maps Doesn't Work

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I have been following the code in the following article,

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polyline-map-overlay/

I have it working well in iOS but whenever I run Android - the polyline route isn't drawn on the map. The map is drawn but the route does not appear.

No errors or warnings are given.

I have put breakpoints in both the methods in the Android CustomMapRenderer (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polyline-map-overlay/#Creating_the_Custom_Renderer_on_Android) but neither breakpoints are hit.

Any suggestions would be appreciated for how to call these methods and get the polyline drawn in the android app.

Thanks again.

Comment: Put codes here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have registered the custom renderer, 
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]. The same sample code works fine for me.